# Return difference of list

Tags: python, list, comparison

I seem to bet getting no returned value on the difference of list old_urls and new_urls. This script is supposed to constantly poll until a difference append the difference and return the difference. Then back to def newresponse()

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
old_urls = []
new_urls = []


def main():
  s = requests.session()
  url = s.get('https://www.sivasdescalzo.com/sitemaps/en/sitemap-1.xml')
  soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
  all_urls = soup.find_all("url")
  for url in all_urls:
     old_urls.append(url.find('loc').get_text())
def newresponse():
  s = requests.session()
  url = s.get('https://www.sivasdescalzo.com/sitemaps/en/sitemap-1.xml')
  soup2 = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
  all_newurls = soup2.find_all("url")
  for urls in all_newurls:
     new_urls.append(urls.find('loc').get_text())

def monitorchange():
  x = list(set(new_urls) - set(old_urls))
  print "looking for change"
  while True:
     s =requests.session()
     url = s.get('https://www.sivasdescalzo.com/sitemaps/en/sitemap-1.xml')
     soup3 = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
     if new_urls != old_urls:
         return x
         old_urls.append(x)
         continue
     elif url.status_code==403:
         print "bannned"
     else:
         time.sleep(60)

main()
newresponse()
monitorchange()
```

Answer (score 0):

With def you are defining a function, not calling it. Your main() and newresponse() functions are never called. As a consequence, your old and new lists will remain empty and cannot show any difference.

Comment: on the bottom i am calling each function individually  aren't I? main() newresponse() monitorchange()

Comment: Sorry - didn't scroll down. May have been a bit late yesterday. Anyhow: perhaps it is just the order of your subtraction that doesn't work as you expect? set(l1)-set(l2) is not the same as set(l2)-set(l1). From the doc: "[-] Return a new set with elements in the set that are not in the other(s)".